# Why do i always get a black image when trying to save the opengl buffer by using freeimage libarary?

Tags: c, opengl, freeimage

Does anybody have experience with using the freeimage library to save the opengl buffer?

Here is my code:

```
void screenshot(const char *ptr){
    GLint viewPort[4]; 
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewPort);  
    GLubyte *pixels=new GLubyte[3*winWidth*winHeight];
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, viewPort[2],viewPort[3], GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);  
    FIBITMAP* image = FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBits(pixels,viewPort[2], viewPort[3],3*viewPort[2] 
    ,24,FI_RGBA_RED, FI_RGBA_GREEN_MASK, FI_RGBA_BLUE_MASK,false);
    FreeImage_Save(FIF_BMP, image, ptr, 0);
    FreeImage_Unload(image);
    delete pixels;
}
```

Why do I always get a black image?

Comment: Have you tried doing any debugging at all? Try checking the `pixels` var after you call `glReadPixels`. Make sure you're calling this after you draw your objects and not immediately after `glClear`.

Comment: yeah,you're right, this is where going wrong, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't set from which buffer to read from. If you want to take the screenshot *after* the buffer swap, then you must read from the front buffer. If you want to take the screenshot *before* the buffer swap, read from the back buffer.

Comment: but how can I read the front buffer, simply add a function glreadbuffer(GL_FRONT) before using the screenshot function?

Comment: @XiaojunZhao: Yes, that's exactly how you do it.